# Test for multiple substrings inside a single string?

Tags: python, substring

Purpose of the code:

1. Ask the user to type in a filename.
2. If that filename contains certain substrings, then that filename is invalid. The program "rejects" and asks for a new filename.
3. If filename does not contain those substrings, then the filename is valid and the program "accepts" it.

**Attempt 1**:

```
while True:
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file:")

    if "FY" in filename or "FE" in filename or "EX1" in filename or "EX2" in filename:
        print "Sorry, this filename is not valid."
    else:
        print "This filename is valid"
        break
```

(I'm leaving out the case-checking on the input just to keep the examples clean).

My issue comes with comparing the multiple substrings against the input filename. I wanted to keep all of the substrings in a tuple instead of having a huge `if or` line. I figured that way it would be easier for whoever takes over the code to find and add to the tuple if need be, instead of having to extend the conditional statement.

**Attempt 2** (with tuple):

```
BAD_SUBSTRINGS = ("FY", "FE", "EX1","EX2")

while True:
    valid = True
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file:")

    for substring in BAD_SUBSTRINGS:
        if substring in filename:
            valid = false
            break

    if not valid:
        print "Sorry, this filename is not valid"
    else:
        print "This filename is valid"
        break
```

But I feel like Attempt 2 isn't the most pythonic way of accomplishing what I want? I would like to avoid the `for` loop and the `valid` boolean if at all possible.

Is there some way I could make Attempt 2 more compact? Or should I just go back to Attempt 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
BAD_SUBSTRINGS = ("FY", "FE", "EX1","EX2")

while True:
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file:")

    if any(b in filename for b in BAD_SUBSTRINGS):
        print("Sorry, this filename is not valid")
    else:
        print("This filename is valid")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the "any" keyword. I'm going to read up on it now.

Comment: Check out the `all` keyword while you're there :-)

Comment: @andraiamatrix: `any` isn't a keyword, it's a built-in function.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
if any(x in filename for x in BAD_SUBSTRINGS):
```